Imported texture displaying as flat black
I've recently started using Blender and I'm having trouble getting my texture to display properly on my 3D model. By 3D scanning an object, I produced the files

0518_04_tex.obj
0518_04_tex.mtl
0518_04_tex.jpg

They're all in the same directory and the mtl file contains the following:
newmtl material_0
map_Kd ./0518_04_tex.jpg

When I import the obj, the texture appears to have been imported and associated with the obj correctly; it appears under Material > Surface > Base Color. However, when I switch to Viewpoint Shading, the model is entirely black rather than textured as expected. A screenshot is below:

Here is what the shader editor shows:

There shouldn't be any black even in the texture; the colors should be sand, orange, and burgundy. Can anyone help me to resolve this and properly map the colors onto the model?
Here is a link to the files if they would be useful.
Thank you for any help you can offer!

Funny, @3fingeredfrog didn't get any texture imported, and I got it imported perfectly: https://i.imgur.com/yDYHbnA.png Maybe double check you got all three files in the same folder with no non-latin characters in any of the folders of the file path.

@Lauloque, Well that's quite easy to explain. I didn't understand what .mtl  (material library file) files are used for so didn't bother to download that one. My bad. I have just added that file to the folder with the other to files (.obj and .jpg) and now, as you suggested the the object imports correctly with the texture applied to it. So will delete my answer.

@Gnomeo Gnomemaker Perhaps try manually reloading the texture into the Image texture node.

@3fingeredfrog I've checked these (re-importing and special characters) and neither of those is the problem. What versions of Blender are you running?

4.2.1 but it shouldn't matter. in your screenshot we can see your material icon is textured, so it seems it did get the texture alright. Maybe the issue is in the viewport settings, so try in a new clean scene without changing any rendering/viewport option aside from switching to material preview. It could also be a graphics drivers issues or your system not meeting the requirements. If all this is ok., it would be simpler if you could share your blend file.

@Lauloque, thank you - you might have solved it with the requirements. I have only 500 MB of VRAM on my graphics card, though it has 8 GB available. I'm not sure what OpenGL version I have. The rest should be fine - I have a 16-core CPU and Windows 10. I can solve this by just allocating more graphics card RAM to VRAM, right? Also, I've started a clean blend file and uploaded it to the Google Drive link in the post, in case that is useful.

PS This model has a very dense mesh - would simplifying it be another workaround?

would simplifying it be another workaround? it never hurts trying, but i don't think so. what are your cpu and gpu model exactly?

@Lauloque My computer is an ASUS VivoBook S712UA-IS79. Its CPU is an AMD Ryzen 7-5700U. Unfortunately, my graphics card is listed only as "AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics" without further specification everywhere I know to look - from the Device Manager to the product specs listed online. I was only able to find out how much RAM my graphics card has using the DirectX Diagnostic Tool. And you'd be right that simplifying doesn't help - I just tried importing a small PNG in Grease Pencil and even that shows up black. I've been unable to find a way to check my OpenGL version as well...

I just returned from the local library, where I'd had success with the model on some older machines. I just installed Blender 4.1 and the model displays with the texture perfectly. I'll use that for now as a workaround and don't want to trouble you any longer, but if you are interested in further sleuthing, I'd always be interested to know the cause of the problem - it would be nice to be able to stay up to date, after all.

From the i7 10510U specs it seems to be fine.  I also opened the file, and it was fine too. So again, check your graphics driver. If that still isn't working, then I'd lean on it being a bug. In which case, please see Where to Report a Bug

In the meantime, I close this topic. If it isn't a bug or get any update on the nature of the issue, please [edit] your question, it will queue it up for reopening. If you find an answer, please comment here so that I can open the question, and you will be able to post the answer in the right place.
